# MeteorJS queries are super slow if users have active sessions

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor app, I have a function that performs some operations on documents. It first fetches the data, does some server-side adjustment and then updates the document properties again. I sometimes need to run it on many documents (thousands, up to 250k).

The normal speed is under 2s for 1000 documents (fetch documents one by one, and after some local data processing, update is one by one; no batch updates, so it runs fairly quick). But if the webserver has been running for a while, and users are logged on, it takes forever to run this function (e.g. 160s for 1000 documents).

I have to log all users off (db.users.update({}, {$set: {"services.resume.loginTokens": []}}, {multi: true}) ) to get the speed back. Once I run the DB query, the execution speed is back at ~2s/1000.

What is the problem? It should not be index related as it would be much slower. Also, there are no logs on the DB side to indicate the DB is the problem and DB does not have any high CPU usage. The webserver runs at 100% though (except for this, the webserver never reaches even 15%).

The webserver is AWS T2.small and the amount of logged in users (they are idle anyway as I do it at night) is around 10. They have some open subscriptions, I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this is an observer related issue, as each logged-in user is likely subscribed to the set of documents that are being updated.

First thing I would try is to do the operation as a [MongoDB Bulk Operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/). That way all the documents are changed at once and the observers & subscriptions will run after the update has finished rather than after each individual change.

The example [given in the Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#bulk-data-changes) is specific to the Todos example app, but gives you an idea of how to set up and run a bulk op in Meteor:

```js
// This is how to get access to the raw MongoDB node collection that the Meteor server collection wraps
const batch = Lists.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

//Mongo throws an error if we execute a batch operation without actual operations, e.g. when Lists was empty.
let hasUpdates = false;
Lists.find({todoCount: {$exists: false}}).forEach(list => {
  const todoCount = Todos.find({listId: list._id}).count();
  // We have to use pure MongoDB syntax here, thus the `{_id: X}`
  batch.find({_id: list._id}).updateOne({$set: {todoCount}});
  hasUpdates = true;
});

if(hasUpdates){
  // We need to wrap the async function to get a synchronous API that migrations expects
  const execute = Meteor.wrapAsync(batch.execute, batch);
  return execute();
}
```

Other options include ripping out the reactivity from your data handling so updates aren't all sent to the client automatically. Which is a bit more involved

Comment: I believe that is the right answer, thank you! I will have to figure out how to solve it, as the updating code is quite complex (360 rows) and produces unique data for each document. 

It may cause more issues once I get more users as every update should re-trigger observers for all users (but everyone should be subscribed just to their own data).

Anyway, how many people do use Meteor? I can't find any in New Zealand :-(.